# how to get specific fields from get_user_meta()

Tags: user-meta

I use `$data = get_user_meta ( $user_id);` to get all data. But only need some fields like gender - city - answer.

How can I filter this in get_user_meta()?

Answer (score 9):

The function's arguments are as follows: user ID, custom field name (meta key), data return method (optional).

So if you wanted to grab data in usermeta with the key of 'member_zip_code', you would run:

```
get_user_meta( $user_id, 'member_zip_code', true );
```

Alternatively, in your prior method, you could grab the additional data like this:

```
$data = get_user_meta ( $user_id);

$data['member_zip_code'][0];
```

Comment: how did you get `member_zip_code` ?

Comment: @Foysal, that one is a custom field. You can find the default fields here: [Are the default entries for a user in wp_usermeta documented?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/278172/12615)