# Are the default entries for a user in wp_usermeta documented?

Tags: user-meta, customization, documentation

On a fresh vanilla install of wordpress users have default entries like nickename, first_name, last_name and so forth in wp_usermeta. I'm not sure if that changes often or at all but I can't seem to find any documentation what the default entries are.

I would have expected it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_usermeta

Is the default set documented and where?

Reason for asking: I'm building a plugin to replicate settings to other users but would like to exclude the default entries (or at least annotate on them or treat them differently). And to maintain the plugin, I'd like to be able to look those up in case there are changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the code itself:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/user.php#L1376

The above links to a documented list of the meta generated when WordPress generates a new user in the `wp_create_user` function.

From these comments I pulled a quick list:

> user_pass, user_login, user_nicename, user_url, user_email,
>   display_name, nickname, first_name, last_name, description,
>   rich_editing, comment_shortcuts, admin_color, use_ssl,
>   user_registered, show_admin_bar_front, role, locale

Comment: I thought about looking it up in the code but hoped there'd be a website for convinience. Not a second did I think about Trac. How could I mniss that? Incredibly helpful, thanks!